# 2D array prints unstable output

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

My test program here is supposed to take a 1D array and sort it into a 2D array.

The file is 3000 common words from 'a' to 'z'. The setup seems correct and I even get an output that starts out correct. However, after words starting with 'b' I get nothing but nulls.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int listSize = 0;

    File file = new File("3000-Common-Words.txt");

    Initialize a = new Initialize();
    String[] oneArray = a.Initialization(file);

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {

        int sizeCheck = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < 3000; j++) {

            if (oneArray[j].charAt(0) == (char) (i + 97)) {
                sizeCheck++;
            }
            if (sizeCheck > listSize) {
                listSize = sizeCheck;
            }
        }
    }

    String[][] twoArray = new String[26][listSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < listSize; j++) {

            if (oneArray[j].charAt(0)==(char)(i+97)){
                twoArray[i][j]=oneArray[j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < listSize; j++) {
            System.out.println(twoArray[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

The initialisation of the first array is correct (I've checked the output).

I see why my array stops before 'c'. Its because I've got `oneArray[j]` but I'm still stuck on how to fill the array...

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic to populate the array is slightly flawed.
You have correctly worked out the minimum dimension for the sparse matrix.
It will be 26 by highest number of words in any letter of the alphabet.
However, you have not chosen independent iteration counters for reading the word list and populating the array.

Here is a working solution:

```
public class WordSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int listSize = 0;

        String[] oneArray = {"a1","b1","c1","d1","e1","f1","g1","h1","i1","j1","k1","l1","m1","n1","o1","p1","q1","r1","s1","t1","u1","v1","w1","x1","y1","z1","a2","b2","d2","g2","n2","l2","z2","v2","g3","h3","p0","h9","r5","t3","o9","l7","h6","f5","q5",};

        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {

            int sizeCheck = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < oneArray.length; j++) {

                if (oneArray[j].charAt(0) == (char) (i + 97)) {
                    sizeCheck++;
                }
                if (sizeCheck > listSize) {
                    listSize = sizeCheck;
                }
            }
        }

        String[][] twoArray = new String[26][listSize];

        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            int k = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < oneArray.length; j++) {
                if (oneArray[j].charAt(0)==(char)(i+97)){
                    twoArray[i][k++]=oneArray[j];
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < listSize; j++) {
                System.out.println(twoArray[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh of course, thank you! Yes, the second array needed to be conducive to `oneArray.length`. I like the idea of putting k++ right inside the statement `twoArray[i][k++]=oneArray[j]`. I don't quite understand the indexing of `oneArray`, this is something i'll work on next. CHEERS!

Comment: @DevlinWyatt I am glad to be of assistance my friend. I wonder if the Correct answer should also be a Useful answer?

Comment: Yes it should but I don't know how to label it as such. Oh i did but it doesn't show up for me.

Answer (score 0):

sizeCheck will be the number of words that start with the letter.
listSize will be the maximum of those.
However in your second loop

```
for (int j = 0; j < listSize; j++) {

        if (oneArray[j].charAt(0)==(char)(i+97)){
            twoArray[i][j]=oneArray[j];
        }
    }
```

you always only "scan" the first "listSize" amount of words in the first array, which actually is 3000 words long. So don't use j for iterating thru "oneArray", instead use another variable for this.

Comment: `oneArray` must be completely traversed in order to populate `twoArray`. Hence `listSize` must  be replaced by `oneArray.length` in the for loop you have suggested.